# Adding Promo text to set of Magento Products

Tags: magento, promotions

Working in Magento 2.2.10 and I am wanting to advertise a special promotion on my product pages with text in a banner or something on the actual product age but am sure of how to do this. I was originally thinking of just adding the text to the Description box in the Content section, but I have almost 1,000 in the set and do not want to have to change it manually. This promo is also only running for 4 months and we do not want to have to re-edit all of the pages to remove this information when the time comes.

I want it to read something similar to the following:
"This product comes with a free Velux Active Gateway at $150 value. The gateway connects your VELUX solar-powered or electric products, indoor climate sensor, and departure switch. It also connects to the internet via your Wi-Fi router to enable the operation of your VELUX solar-powered or electric products from your smartphone. Only one gateway is needed for each house or apartment."

It would be great if we didn't need an extension to complete this. Perhaps if someone can walk us through the Design/schedule design update function, that would do it. Not really sure. Thanks in advance for any ideas/solutions!

Answer (score 0):

You could add all the products that you want to modify into a new category via mass update, and then add a layout update into the PDP vía category. i.e. (promo products). I hope this could help you.